# Why does the data observed on a UART/RS232 bus look different between a logic analyzer and an STM32 Debugger?

Tags: stm32, uart, rs232, imu

I'm trying to communicate with a BNO055 using an STM32L552ZET6Q microcontroller via UART. The BNO055 is on a separate board, and connected to the STM32 via a 1.5M cable. Additionally, there are MAX3232CUE+T RS232 chips on either side of the cable, converting the UART data to RS232 and back again. This is to make sure communications aren't corrupted by EMI or simple distance while traveling through the cable.

When observing the data arriving from a logic analyzer, it looks different from what is displayed on the STM32 Debugger (seen below) Also keep in mind that these were both taken as UART (not RS232) in close proximity to the STM32.
[image: Logic analysis from STM32L5 to BNO055 UART bus]

[image: Debugger display from UART RX]

Included below is the code used to write to and read from the BNO055 via UART:

```
void uartWrite(bno055_uart *chip, uint8_t reg, uint8_t len, uint8_t *buf)
{
    uint8_t status;
    uint8_t feedback[2];
    uint8_t transmit_buf[128] = {0xAA, 0x00, reg, len};
    for(uint8_t x = 0; x < len; x++)
    {
        transmit_buf[x + 4] = buf[x];
    }
    status = HAL_UART_Transmit(&chip->uart_bus, transmit_buf, (len + 4), 50);
    //bno055_delay(10);
    if(status == HAL_OK)
    {
        HAL_UART_Receive(&chip->uart_bus, feedback, 2, 50);

        switch(feedback[1])
        {
        case 0x01:
            return;
            break;
        case 0x03:
            printf("Write Failure in BNO055 UART");
            break;
        case 0x04:
            printf("Invalid Register map address");
            break;
        case 0x05:
            printf("Register Map Write Disabled");
            break;
        case 0x06:
            printf("Wrong Start Byte");
            break;
        case 0x07:
            printf("Bus Over Run Error");
            break;
        case 0x08:
            printf("Max Length Error");
            break;
        case 0x09:
            printf("Min Length Error");
            break;
        case 0x0A:
            printf("Receive Character Timeout");
            break;
        }
        return;
    }

    else
    {
        printf("Error Occurred/r/n");
        return;
    }
}

void uartRead(bno055_uart *chip, uint8_t reg, uint8_t len, uint8_t *data)
{
    uint8_t transmit_buf[128] = {0xAA, 0x01, reg, len};

    HAL_UART_Transmit(&chip->uart_bus, transmit_buf, 4, 50);
    //bno055_delay(10);
    HAL_UART_Receive(&chip->uart_bus, data, (len+2), 50);
    if(data[0] != 0xBB)
    {
        switch(data[1])
        {
            case 0x02:
                printf("Read Failure");
                break;
            case 0x04:
                printf("Register Map Invalid Address");
                break;
            case 0x05:
                printf("Register Map Write Disabled");
                break;
            case 0x06:
                printf("Wrong Start Byte");
                break;
            case 0x07:
                printf("Bus over run error");
                break;
            case 0x08:
                printf("Max length error");
                break;
            case 0x09:
                printf("Min length error");
                break;
            case 0x0A:
                printf("receive character timeout");
        }

    }
}
```

*Edit 1:* Below is a picture of the STM32 clock configuration in STM32CubeIDE. Both devices have external 32.768kHz clock sources attached to them.

[image: STM32L5 Clock setup]
*End of Edit 1*

*Edit 2:* I finally had a chance to try running the device with HAL_MAX_DELAY and it looks like the STM32 doesn't realize that anything has arrived on the bus. broken down, it shows the following:

a request is sent for the BNO055's id (0xA0). This command is composed of a start byte (0xAA), Read or Write (0x01 for read), What is being read (0x00) and how many bytes of data the BNO055 should send back (1, 0x01).

The response back from the BNO055 is success (0xBB), length of the data (0x01) and the data (0xA0).

[image: Logic analysis with HAL_MAX_DELAY]

However, the HAL_UART_RECEIVE function just keeps waiting for something to show up.

*End of Edit 2*

Below are links to the BNO055 datasheet, and BNO055 UART application notes respectively, as well as the datasheet for the MAX3232CUE+T:
[Link to BNO055 Datasheet](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/BST_BNO055_DS000_12.pdf)
[Link to BNO055 UART application notes](https://www.bosch-sensortec.com/media/boschsensortec/downloads/application_notes_1/bst-bno055-an012.pdf)
[Link to MAX3232CUE+T Datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/max3222-max3241.pdf)

I'm still collecting additional information, so if you have any specific questions, please let me know. Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: Hard to say. What baud rate you are using, and do both devices support it within allowable tolerance?

Comment: @Justme 115200 baud rate on the STM32 UART and BNO055. From what I could see in the BNO055 application notes I linked, that's the only supported rate. I could be wrong, but I didn't see any other possibilities. Strangely, I didn't see any mention of baud rate in the BNO055 datasheet.

Comment: The baud rate is described in the datasheet UART protocol section. But have you measured the baud rates if they match? What clock source and frequency you are using on STM32? What clock source and frequency are you using on sensor?

Comment: @Justme The STM32's input clock frequency is 32.768kHz, coming from a VMK3-9005-32K7680000 . The BNO055 uses a ECS-.327-12.5-17X-TR as an external clock source (also 32.768kHz).

Comment: That STM32 can't run on an external 32768 Hz crystal. Even if it did, it could not reach 115200 with it. So while it may use the LSE crystal for trimming a higher clock, be sure about what exact frequency it runs with, and what tolerance the frequency has.

Comment: @Justme I think I misinterpreted your question, at least regarding the STM32. I rechecked the setup and clock going to UART5 says it's 110MHz, coming from PCLK1. I've got a picture of my clock setup that I'm adding to the main question now, if that helps

Comment: No, the clock source and accuracy are still hidden. PCLK comes from SYSCLK (I assume that is 110 MHz too), and thus SYSCLK comes from PLL, but how is the PLL set up and what is the clock source for PLL? MSI, HSI16, or HSE?

Comment: @Justme It comes from MSI.

Comment: And how is MSI set up? What frequency? Is it trimmed by the LSE? What coefficients the PLL uses to get it up to 110 MHz?

Comment: The datasheet says the tolerance of MSI should be within band of error for UART comms. The MCU should run within 2% of 110 MHz, and if tuned by LSE, within 0.1% if LSE is accurate. Have you tried to send and receive data with a PC set to 115200 bps, with both the STM32, and the sensor? Although the exact UART init on the STM32 is not shown, it should be able to reach 115200 within 0.5%.

Comment: @Justme According to the STM32L552xx datasheet (section 3.11), the MSI "can automatically be trimmed by the hardware to be better than +-0.25% accuracy". MSI can generate 12 frequencies, from 100kHz to 48MHz.

Comment: I know. I spent the last 10 minutes reading it. When trimmed, it is not 4.000 MHz. The exact value is 3.997696 MHz, or at least they round it to 3.998 MHz. So, it's not exactly 4 MHz but close enough.

Comment: The value you're seeing in the 1st 4 bytes of `buffer` look suspiciously like a RAM address to me: 0x200026ac. I don't have a good reason for why `HAL_UART_Receive()` would have done that though ...

Comment: @brhans I didn't consider that possibility before. Actually, I just realized I haven't tried the UART_RECEIVE with a HAL_MAX_DELAY. The highest I've tried it is 500ms, but I could easily miss that. At least this way, I can actually find out if the UART is reading anything. I just assumed it must be receiving something because the logic analyzer was reading values that were arriving on the same line as the UART, having already travelled the full length of the cable

Comment: So which STM32 board you have? To which pin is the UART configured, and is the data wire actually connected to that pin?

Comment: @Justme It's a custom board, but it's configured as a NUCLEO-L552ZE-Q. I'm using UART4, Receive & Transmit, 115200Bits/s Baud rate, 8 Bits word length, no parity, 1 Stop Bit, RX on pin 112 (PC11), TX on pin 111 (PC10). I can also confirm that the test pins my logic analyzer are connected to are showing proper continuity to the STM32 pins.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I've got it working!

So, this one was weird, and I'm not 100% sure I understand what happened, but I'm reasonably close.

As I understand it, the BNO055's UART RX buffer was sort of hanging on to old data, preventing it from reading new data and causing it to time out. I added a HAL_UART_AbortReceive() before running HAL_UART_Receive() and it works like a charm! I'm collecting Acceleration, Orientation, Euler & Quaternion data, all over UART/RS232!